# Approach to modify the database without logging the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I have a React frontend with a Node + MySQL backend, I'm sending an email to an user with two buttons to accept or decline a quote. What I'm trying to achieve is **to make the buttons in the email modify the database securely without the user having to log into his account**. My idea is to have two routes, one that sends the email containing the buttons which will have a url to my website with the jwt token on its parameters, and another for verifying said token and making the changes to the db. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
app.post("/email-quote", async function (req, res) {
  const payload = {
    uid: req.body.user.id,
    quoteId: req.body.quote.id,
    accepted: // true for the accept button, false for the decline button
  }

  const secret = ?
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret);

  // ...
  // Generate and send email with buttons containing the url + the token
});
```

When the user clicks one of the buttons, I re-direct him to my website and there I can extract the token and verify its validity:

```
app.get("/verify-email-quote/:token", async function (req, res) {
  const decodedJwt = jwt.decode(req.params.token);
  const secret = ?

  const verifiedJwt = jwt.verify(req.params.token, secret);

  if (verifiedJwt) {
    // Make the changes to the db
  }
});
```

I wasn't able to find any examples trying to achieve something similar on the web, so I have these questions:

- Would a jwt token be a good approach to achieve this?
- If yes, what secret should I use to create the token?
- If no, what other solutions could I look into?

Comment: So these are on two completely separate domains? The user id comes from the request body, how does that work? It doesn't look like this will be secure at all, but I can't comment fully as I am not 100% sure on what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are 100% in charge of to which email you send what content. This means you've got enough means of verification. Hide a uuid hash behind the Button where the user action happens as GET parameter. Then when he clicks it he gets redirected to your site. There you can check whether the GET param given matches with the one you created for the email address -> IF yes then the action is verified :)

Comment: @noa-dev You're right, I didn't thought about the fact that the token will be sent only to the right email. So the uuid hash would be the secret string used to verify the tokens validity?

Comment: @Rezaa91 Both routes are on the backend, the user id being on the token's payload is just an example, since I could also use a hash and decode it to get the actual user id. It's just an example of two routes: one that generates the token and sends it through email as buttons, and another one that validates the token (which will be used when the user clicks on any of the buttons from his email). It's just that I don't know what a good secret would be to sign the token. Or if there are better approaches to achieve this same functionality (I'm pretty new to this)

Comment: @Jorche Yes. The combination of the uuid hash and the user email, both can be provided in the GET params or however you like and is more than enough validity. Any password recovery tool works like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it this way.

The secret does not matter. As long as the secret is secret

It doesn't need to be a jwt token. It can just be a normal token. The incentive to using jwt is that you can embed a payload into the token. For your case, it looks like it is exclusively for verification purposes. It doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things, but if you don't have jwt already implemented, there's no need to go through all that extra work just for this use case.